# How to print characters before the first hyphen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print only the characters before the first hyphen in serialNumber?

```
   "cmdbID":"d01aacda21b7c181aaaaa16dc4bcbca",
   "serialNumber":"VBlock740-4239340361f4d-0f6d9d6ad46879",
   "vdcLocation":"Data Center-San Diego (SDC)",
```

Here's what my code does so far:

```
with open('test-payload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
#split_string = data.serialNumber.split("-", "1")
#substring = split_string[0]
#print(substring)
print(data['serialNumber'])

$ VBlock740-4239340361f4da72-0f6d9d672ad46879
```

Comment: Use the `split()` function. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `split()` function, create a list with each part of a string that separates each part by the specified string or regex (?). If nothing is specified, it defaults to spaces (`" "`). We can use `split("-")` in your case to split each part of the serial number into parts separated by `-`. Then, we can access the first part of the list. For example:

```
with open('test-payload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    serialNumber = data["serialNumber"]
    splittedSerialNumber = serialNumber.split("-") # returns splitted list
    firstPart = splittedSerialNumber[0] # accessing the first part of the splitted list
```

Edit: grammar

Comment: I added some original code I omitted yesterday. Seems I was on right track. What got me over the hump was understanding to set the serialNumber as a new variable and going from there. Thanks so much!